# ELK | Log file grok filtered format not pushing into elastic search

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I have log file having below format to extract into elastic search, but logstash filtered data not pushing into elastic search.

Same grok filtered configuration am able to get it from kibana devtools

Sample logfile:
OCDE - 2019-05-22 13:24:34.000 ERROR org.ramyam.ocde.task.NBALookupTask.checkResponsesToBeProcessed - checkResponsesToBeProcessed started : Wed May 22 13:24:34 IST 2019

Filebeat configuration:

filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - C:\data\logs\OCDE.log
  document_type: ocde

logstash configuration:

```
input {
    file {
            type => "ocde"
            path => "C:\data\logs\OCDE.log"
    }
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl  => false
  }
}

filter {
        grok {
            match => [ "message" ,'%{DATA:moduleName} - %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:loggerTime}\s+%{LOGLEVEL:level}\s+%{JAVACLASS:className}\.%{DATA:methodName} - %{GREEDYDATA:loggermsg}}']
        }
}

output {
        if [type]=="ocde" 
        {
            elasticsearch
              {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                #manage_template => false
                index => "enliven_be_log_yyyymmdd"
                document_type=> ocde
            }   
        }
}
```

I am expecting below result from an above configuration in elastic search

```
{
  "level": "ERROR",
  "loggerTime": "2019-05-22 13:24:34.000",
  "moduleName": "OCDE",
  "methodName": "checkResponsesToBeProcessed",
  "className": "org.ramyam.ocde.task.NBALookupTask",
  "loggermsg": "checkResponsesToBeProcessed started : Wed May 22 13:24:34 IST 2019"
}
```

Can anyone please explain or share sample configuration what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

You can try below grok pattern -

```
%{DATA:moduleName}%{SPACE}*-%{SPACE}*%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:loggerTime}%{SPACE}*%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}*%{JAVACLASS:className}\.%{DATA:methodName}%{SPACE}*-%{SPACE}*%{GREEDYDATA:loggermsg}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your grok from:

```
%{DATA:moduleName} - %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:loggerTime}\s+%{LOGLEVEL:level}\s+%{JAVACLASS:className}\.%{DATA:methodName} - %{GREEDYDATA:loggermsg}}
```

to:

```
%{DATA:moduleName} - %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:loggerTime}\s+%{LOGLEVEL:level}\s+%{JAVACLASS:className}\.%{DATA:methodName} - %{GREEDYDATA:loggermsg}
```

To validate this, use http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ and paste the log message you provided into the "[image]

Your pattern works fine, you just had one extra bracket at the end.